# Crop an image using scaling and dragging the rectangle

Tags: java, android, crop, whatsapp, image-capture

I am new to android and i want to learn how to implement crop image using rectangle that can be dragged and scaled over the image and finally crop  image with rectangle boundaries(the same crop activity used in whatsapp profile picure change). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: there's a nice looking library that I recently discovered [here](https://github.com/edmodo/cropper).

---

When I did this previously, I branched the code from the SoundCloud implementation (which was originally branched from the open source Android camera app) on GitHub, but it looks like there was a library released in August last year that you could use.

Link to it [here](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/08/cropper/)

Comment: 2nd link is dead. If it was for Soundcloud cropper, i found it [here](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop)